# Handle dojo dijit before destroy recursive

Tags: dijit.layout, contentpane

I have a web app that loads it´s forms via ajax into a dijit.layout.ContentPane. 
Every time a user navigates from this form into another, the content pane is destroyed with destroyRecursive() and another form is loaded.
I was trying to handle some "pre"-destroyRecursive event but there isn´t one so i need to extend the content pane to allow the execution of javascript code before destroyRecursive is called. 
I am not posting any code mainly because i don´t how to do this and this is my question.

Thanks

Comment: Extend `ContentPane` then override `destroyRecursive`?

Comment: Yes i know....well, could you show me how?